# Bootstrap center alert close button when alert has multiple lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty simple problem:

This code:
http://www.bootply.com/DiP1WtXyho

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  Line 1
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  Line 1
  <br>
  Line 2
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

results in this problem:
[image]

As you can see, in the first alert the close button is centered. In the second alert it is not. How can I fix that? (If possible without adding a complete table construct into all my alerts.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternate method would be to set your close box to be `absolute` positioned but an unfortunate side effect is you have to hard code the top `margin`.

```
.alert-info {
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px; /* Needs to be half the height of the element (21/2) */
}
```

I [recreated this in a js.fiddle if you want to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/oen2e4ph/). Hope that helps.

**EDIT**
It seems that the `height` needs to be based off the close box (X) rather than the `top-padding`. Element height is `21px` so `-10px` works well. [Updated the Fiddle to showcase this update](https://jsfiddle.net/oen2e4ph/1/).

Comment: But wouldn't we have to also subtract half the height of the "x"? Maybe line-height should also be set to 0 to avoid that?

Comment: @Forivin hmm good point. I think the margin-top adjustment needs to be based off the actual height of the X rather than the top padding. If you remove the padding -10px is still needed. Ill update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To align `close` button verticaly center add below css will make it `vertically aligned centered`.

**NOTE**

Giving only `line-height:0` will make it center but it will effect those `alerts` having single line text. **Thanks**

```
.alert{
   position:relative;
}
.close{
  position:absolute;
  top:48%;
  right:35px;
  line-height:0;
}
```

**Thats it**